# What symbol should I use for nonnegative real numbers

Tags: notation

I know that positive real numbers can be denoted in the following way:
$$
\mathbb{R}^{+} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: x>0\}
$$

I also encounter this symbol:
$$
\mathbb{R}^{>0} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: x>0\}
$$

My question is:

1. How can I denote nonnegative real numbers, theoretically it should be $\mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$, but I think it is not elegant way.
2. I have the same question about two dimensional case. I met the following notation. Is it correct?
   $$
   \mathbb{R}_{+} = \{(x, y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x, y \geq 0 \}
   $$

Comment: Note that the linked question does cover both positive and non-negative reals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often see people use $\mathbb{R}_0^+$.

Concerning your second question: it would be better to add the superscript 2: $\mathbb{R}^2_+$. Otherwise it is not necessarily clear that the $\mathbb{R}^2$ is referred to.

Comment: Thank you! What about two dimensional case?

Comment: @JonasAl-Hadad Just added that, sorry!

Comment: Ok, thanks! I just wonder about cases: $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x, y\geq 0\}$ and $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x, y>0\}$. I think that in both cases symbol $\mathbb{R}_{+}^2$ can be used. But I would like to have two different symbols ;)

Comment: @JonasAl-Hadad Why not use $\mathbb{R}^2_{>0}$ for the latter case to avoid misinterpretation?

Comment: Ok, so I think the best way is to use: $\mathbb{R}_{0}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}_{+}^2$

Answer (score 9):

I have often seen $\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$.

In the end, it doesn't really matter as long as the notation you use is not too heavy, and you define it well.

Comment: This notation has the virtue of being self-explanatory. Also, the subscript doesn't interfere with any dimension indicator that would normally attach to the  $\Bbb R$ as a supersccript.

Answer (score 1):

I've usually seen (and use):
\begin{align}
\mathbf R_+^{\phantom{*}}=\{\,x\in\mathbf R\mid  x\ge 0\,\}\\[1ex]
\mathbf R_+^*=\{\,x\in\mathbf R\mid  x > 0\,\}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You can use any compact notation of your choice as long as you define it well. Suppose, for example, that I wish to use $\mathcal R$ to denote the nonnegative reals, then since $\mathbb R^+$ is a fairly well-known notation for the positive reals, I can just say, Let $$\mathcal R = \mathbb R^+ \cup \{0\}.$$

Something similar can be done for any $n$-dimensional euclidean space, where you wish to deal with the members in the first $2^n$-ant of the space and the origin $(0,0,0,0...)$, where there are $n$ zeros. Just pick a suitable compact notation and define it beforehand by using the set operation $\cup$, or more simply just use $\mathcal R$ as defined above and the cartesian product $\times$.